# Kafka connect - Failed to connect to localhost port 8083: Connection refused

Tags: linux, kubernetes, apache-kafka-connect

I have an application that relies on a kafka service.

With Kafka connect, I'm getting an error when trying to `curl localhost:8083`, on the Linux VM that's running the kubernetes pod for Kafka connect.

`curl -v localhost:8083` gives:

- Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8083/
- Trying 127.0.0.1...
- connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8083 failed: Connection refused
- Failed to connect to localhost port 8083: Connection refused
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8083: Connection refused

`kubectl get po -o wide` for my kubernetes namespace gives:

[image]

When I check open ports using `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` I don't see 8083 listed. The kafka connect pod is running and there's nothing suspicious in the logs for the pod.

There's a kubernetes manifest that I think was probably used to set up the Kafka connect service, these are the relevant parts. I'd really appreciate any advice about how to figure out why I can't curl localhost:8083

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: kafka-connect
   namespace: my-namespace
spec:

   ...

   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: connect
     spec:
        containers:
          - name: kafka-connect
            image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:3.0.1
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8083

            env:
              
              - name: CONNECT_REST_PORT
                value: "8083"
              - name: CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
                value: "kafka-connect"

        volumes:
          - name: connect-plugins
            persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: pvc-connect-plugin
          - name: connect-helpers          
            secret:
              secretName: my-kafka-connect-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-connect
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: connect  
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8083
  selector:
    app: connect
```

Comment: May be you can share the outputs of ```kubectl get po -n {your_namespace} -o wide``` and ```kubectl get ingress -n {your_namespace} -o=yaml``` alongwith the output of ```curl -v localhost:8083```

Comment: Basically, you should be concerned about the verbose output of curl command and the output of kubectl get ingress for any errors if present. Otherwise, IMHO you are doing wrong curl command, you should run curl localhost:8083 when you have ssh into your pod from your node.

Comment: I follow this link for troubleshooting such issues of service not available or Connection refused. Have a look here. 
https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-troubleshooting-ingress-and-services-traffic-flows-547ea867b120

Comment: Thanks @KnockingHeads, you're right, thanks! I needed to curl localhost:8083 from inside the pod. Why can I not curl 8083 when I ssh onto the VM? Why isn't the port exposed on the host VM that has the pods?

Comment: You can access from your node as well. Run ```hostname``` on your VM. It will give you the hostname. Now, instead of using localhost with curl. You can run ```curl <hostname>/<namespace>/<path>```. Like if your hostname is ```abc.corp.xyz.com```, then you can do ```curl http://abc.corp.xyz.com/``` from your node as well. Rest is the k8s basics.

Comment: Thanks @KnockingHeads. I tried `curl hostname:8083/my-kube-namespace/connectors` and `curl hostname:8083/connectors`, but both give me `port 8083: Connection refused`

Comment: I'm running docker, postgres, zookeper and debezium through a docker-compose. I get exactly the same error. and i wonder if when you mean accessing from a pod, you mean accessing through the bash inside a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect to a service running inside your cluster, from outside your cluster, without a little bit of tinkering.

You have three possible solutions:

1. Use a service with type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` to make the service reachable outside the cluster.

   See the [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [kubectl expose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose) documentation.
   **Be aware, depending on your environment, this may expose the service to the internet.**
2. Access using *Proxy Verb:* (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls))

   This only works for HTTP/HTTPS. Use this if your service is not secure
   enough to be exposed to the internet.
3. Access from pod running inside your cluster.

   As you have noticed in the comments, you can `curl` from inside the pod. You can also do this from any other pod running in the same cluster. Pods can communicate with each other without any additional configuration.

---

> Why can I not curl 8083 when I ssh onto the VM?

Pods/services are not reachable from outside the cluster, if not exposed using aforementioned methods (point 1 or 2).

> Why isn't the port exposed on the host VM that has the pods?

It's not exposed on your VM, it's exposed inside your cluster.

---

I would strongly recommend going through [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) documentation to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Pawel (and @KnockingHeads) that's exactly the help I needed